# Component `escape` bubbling up from `select` element

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a modal component. it used to close on press of `escape` button. now I have a `select` option within it. when i press the tab with `select` option and do the `escape` to come out of the `select` element, now my popup as well getting closed. i tried with adding `stopPropagation` but not works.

here is the html: `confirmCancel()` method getting triggered

```
<ibo-custom-modal [isTable]="true" [showModal]="addItemPop" [title]="title" (modalClosed)="confirmCancel()">

  <div (keydown)="($event); $event.stopPropagation()">//not works
    <select (keydown)="calling($event)">//tried here as well
      <option>one</option>
      <option>two</option>
      <option>the</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</ibo-custom-modal>
```

Comment: Which kind of event is (modalClosed)? When does it fire?

Comment: Can you check ESC key handler in modal source code? Even if it's third-party library you need to understand which action it uses - keydown, keyup, keypress... Very probably that event listener add to the document element.
After that you can stopPropagation or stopImmediatePropagation exactly for this event.